# Delphi Twebbrowser change value of textbox.

Tags: delphi, twebbrowser

I'm have some difficulty changing the value of a textbox in twebbrowser. I have tried `WebBrowser1.OleObject.Document.getElementById('verification_control_0').value := 'mytext';` and a few other methods but it doesn't seem to work.

The websites code:

```
 <div id="verification_control_0" class="verification_control">
 <div class="smalltext">
 What are the first 3 letters of our website's name?:<br />
 <input type="text" name="register_vv[q][71]" size="30" value=""  tabindex="6"    class="input_text" />
  </div>
 </div>
```

If you could please show me how to change the value in `<input type="text" name="register_vv[q][71]" size="30" value=""  tabindex="6" class="input_text" />` i would really appreciate it very much. 
Thanks for reading and all replies.

Comment: `WebBrowser1.OleObject.Document.getElementByID('register_vv[q][71]').Value:='test';` seems to work, no?

Comment: Nope, It doesn't work. I get an error message "Method 'value' not supported by automation object".

Comment: Weird, I copy pasted that line from a test app here (XE2-ie8-w7)

Comment: what version are you using?

Comment: If you're question is directed at me, I'm using delphi 2009.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz, your code should work also. see my edit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  col: IHTMLElementCollection;
  el: IHTMLInputElement;
begin
  col := (WebBrowser1.Document as IHTMLDocument3).getElementsByName('register_vv[q][71]');
  if col.length <> 0 then
  begin
    el := col.item(0, 0) as IHTMLInputElement;
    el.value := 'mytext';
  end;
end;
```

In IE8 Standards mode, [`getElementById`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536437.aspx) performs a case-sensitive match on the `ID` attribute only.
In IE7 Standards mode and previous modes, this method performs a case-insensitive match on both the `ID` and `NAME` attributes, which might produce [unexpected results](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200802/beware_of_id_and_name_attribute_mixups_when_using_getelementbyid_in_internet_explorer/).

So if your `TWebBrowser` works with IE7 Standards mode and previous modes `getElementById` should work as well:

```
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  el: IHTMLElement;
  inputElement: IHTMLInputElement;
begin
  el := (WebBrowser1.Document as IHTMLDocument3).getElementById('register_vv[q][71]');
  if Assigned(el) then
    if Supports(el, IID_IHTMLInputElement, inputElement) then
      inputElement.value := 'mytext';
end;
```

Using `getElementsByName` collection to locate elements by `NAME` should be the preferred solution.

---

**EDIT:**
@SertacAkyuz first comment:

```
WebBrowser1.OleObject.Document.getElementByID('register_vv[q][71]').Value:='tes‌​t';
```

I'm pretty sure OP did not test *your* code (which *should* work by default, unless OP explicitly changed IE browsing mode), and used `getElementByID('verification_control_0')` instead - which is a `DIV` element and does  not have method `value` supported. (hence the error message `"Method 'value' not supported by automation object"`).

Comment: +1 (already) and thanks for clearing some confusion on my part.

Answer (score 0):

Your getElementById('verification_control_0') will get the DIV Element, wich doesn't have a 'value'.

Your textbox does not have a ID. For a test change the 'name' attribute to 'id' like this

```
<input type="text" id="register_vv[q][71]" size="30" value=""  tabindex="6" class="input_text" />
```

and change your code like this

```
WebBrowser1.OleObject.Document.getElementById('register_vv[q][71]').value := 'mytext';
```

Comment: The problem is that the website doesn't belong to me. Usually i have no problem getting a value by it's id if it has one. I'm hoping that delphi isn't limited to just getelementbyid.

Answer (score 0):

I had to allow entry of text via touch buttons in to the active element, the below worked:

```
    procedure TMyForm.SendKey(key : string);
    var
    Doc: IHTMLDocument2;
    InputBox : IHtmlInputElement;
    begin
      Doc := WebBrowser1.Document as IHTMLDocument2;

      if Doc.activeElement.isTextEdit then
      begin
        InputBox := Doc.activeElement as IHtmlInputElement;
        InputBox.value := InputBox.value+key;
      end;
    end;
```